# How to sort edges in a special surface mesh

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mesh

Here is a function using the suggestion from the answer given to the question I asked few days back. Lets create a Graphics3D object in Mathematica. I use this 3D geometry data from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?3s9mdtbmbqcmaq9).

```
cd = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "withwake.obj"];
vertices = cd[[1, 2, 1]];
polygons = Flatten[cd[[1, 2, 2, 1]] /. Polygon -> List, 2];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[vertices, Polygon[polygons]]]
```

[image]

For each polygon we create a **list** of numbers pointing to its vertices and followed by the numbers pointing to the polygons each of the edges are connected to. Important to notice is the surface normal; order of nodes defining panels should be counter clockwise. By the right-hand rule if fingers are bended to follow numbering, thumb will show normal vector that should point “outwards” geometry.

Here is a function that creates such a list if all the polygons in the `Graphics3D` object are triangles.

```
EdgeSorting[vertices_, polygons_] := 
Block[{triangleEdges, singleEdges, edgesNeighbors, relations, n, n1,
 n2, trires, triangleNeigbours, TriangleMaker, polygonArea, tring},
(*Split every triangle in 3 edges,with nodes in each edge sorted*)   
triangleEdges = (Sort /@ Subsets[#, {2}]) & /@ polygons;
(*Generate a list of edges*)
singleEdges = Union[Flatten[triangleEdges, 1]];
(*Define a function which,given an edge (node number list),
returns the bordering*)
(*triangle numbers.It's done by working through each of the \
triangles' edges*)
edgesNeighbors[_] = {};
MapIndexed[(edgesNeighbors[#1[[1]]] = 
   Flatten[{edgesNeighbors[#1[[1]]], #2[[1]]}];
  edgesNeighbors[#1[[2]]] = 
   Flatten[{edgesNeighbors[#1[[2]]], #2[[1]]}];
  edgesNeighbors[#1[[3]]] = 
   Flatten[{edgesNeighbors[#1[[3]]], #2[[1]]}];) &, triangleEdges];
(*Build a triangle relation table.Each'1' indicates a triangle \
relation*)
relations = 
ConstantArray[
 0, {triangleEdges // Length, triangleEdges // Length}];
Scan[(n = edgesNeighbors[##];
  If[Length[n] == 2, {n1, n2} = n;
   relations[[n1, n2]] = 1; relations[[n2, n1]] = 1];) &, 
singleEdges];
Print[MatrixPlot[relations]];
(*Build a neighborhood list*)
triangleNeigbours = 
Table[Flatten[Position[relations[[i]], 1]], {i, 
  triangleEdges // Length}];
trires = 
Table[Flatten[{polygons[[i]], triangleNeigbours[[i]]}], {i, 1, 
  Length@polygons}];
TriangleMaker[{a_, b_, c_}] := {vertices[[a]], vertices[[b]], 
 vertices[[c]]};
{trires}
];
```

I don't completely understand the way this function works. And I cant understand how to achieve the following.

1. For each the **triangles** and **quadrilateral** how to form **lists** as mentioned just before.
2. The planer mesh away from the 3D hydrofoil is called wake panel. For each **wake quadrilateral panel/polygon** we need to form a list  of numbers pointing to its vertices followed by numbers pointing to the **two polygons** it is sharing its only edge that connects the wake quadrilateral panel/polygon with the main hydrofoil geometry.

Comment: What are the points you do not understand in your function?

Comment: The `edgesNeighbors` part mainly. I tried with adding `edgesNeighbors[#1[[4]]] = 
   Flatten[{edgesNeighbors[#1[[4]]], #2[[1]]}];` but did not work. And the wakes seems to be more difficult to handle.

Comment: If your code is working for triangles and you have quadrilaterals ... why just don't split them by the diagonal?

Comment: I need the quadrilateral. I need them to use an external program. Simple triangular mesh is not necessary. These quadrilateral are absolute necessary.

Answer (score 5):

To create a list of all the polygons and their neighbours, you could do something like this:

```
neighbours[polygons_] := {#, 
  Flatten@Position[polygons, 
    a_List /; Length[Intersection[a, #]] == 2]} & /@ polygons;
```

Then `neighbours[polygons]` creates a list where the `i`-th entry consists of `polygons[[i]]` and the indices of the neighbours of `polygons[[i]]`.

For the second part of your question, you could do something like

```
wake[polygons_] := 
 Module[{edges, boundaries, wakelist, body}, 
  edges[polylist_] := Flatten[Map[Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] &, polylist], 1];
  boundaries = Cases[Tally[
     edges[polygons], (Sort[#1] == Sort[#2]) &], {a_, b_} /; b == 1 :> a];
  wakelist = 
   DeleteDuplicates[
    Map[Cases[polygons, a_ /; (Length[Intersection[a, #]] == 2)][[1]] &,
      boundaries]];
  {#, Flatten@Position[polygons, a_List /; (Length[Intersection[#, a]] == 2 && 
          Not[MemberQ[wakelist, a]])]} & /@ wakelist]
```

In `wake`, a polygon is considered a wake panel if it contains an edge that doesn't have any neighbouring polygons. I don't know if this is always valid but it seems to work for the example in the question.

**Edit** 
To split the full list of polygons in wake and body polygons, you can do something like

```
split[polygons_] := Module[{edges, boundaries, wakelist}, 
   edges[polylist_] := Flatten[Map[Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] &, polygons], 1];
   boundaries = Cases[Tally[edges[polygons], 
       (Sort[#1] == Sort[#2]) &], {a_, b_} /; b == 1 :> a];
   wakelist = DeleteDuplicates[Map[Cases[polygons, 
        a_ /; (Length[Intersection[a, #]] == 2)][[1]] &, boundaries]];
   {wakelist, Complement[polygons, wakelist]}];
```

Then `split[polygons]` will produce a list of two sublists. The first sublist contains all the polygons belonging to the wake, and the second one all the polygons belonging to the body. Since `split` already separates the wake from the body, we can rewrite `wake` according to

```
wake2[wakelist_, bodylist_] := {#, Flatten@Position[bodylist,
      a_List /; (Length[Intersection[#, a]] == 2)]} & /@ wakelist
```

Then to find the list of body polygons plus the indices of their neighbours, and the list of wake polygons plus the indices of the neighbouring body polygons you can do

```
{wakepols, bodypols} = split[polygons];
bodylist = neighbours[bodypols];
wakelist = wake[wakepols, bodypols];
```

Note that the indices of the polygons in both `bodylist` and `wakelist` now refer to the polygons in `bodypols`, not to the ones in the full list, `polygons`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Your explanation was very lucid. Cheers!!

Comment: @Heike sorry for the off-topic message, but you might want to consider linking your Area 51 profile to your SO profile. (Given your rep level, this will help the site meet the targets to get to the beta stage.)

Comment: @Verbeia I hadn't thought of that. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Heike answer is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist I'm not sure why it didn't work in your case, given you are using the same email address. Perhaps because the username is different.

Comment: @ Heike `neighbours[plygons]` is giving all the polygon relations including the wakes too. How can we exclude the wakes as we can separately get wakes by `wake[polygons]`? Is it possible to get only the triangles and quadrilaterals as a list? I am not able to separate the wakes from `neighbours[plygons]`.

Comment: @ Heike I need the indices to refer to the one in full list. Else it will not work as `bodypols` has only polygons except the wakes but `polygons` has those wakes also as separate polygons.

Comment: @ Heike `wakelist = wake2[wakepols, bodypols];` is the correct one you missed the 2!!

Comment: @ Heike Outward surface normal is also very very important here. The previous solution was fine just the wakes were coming two times. Thanks for your help and we are very close to a solution. Hope you help me.

Comment: @ Heike I want to make input file like in http://www.3dpanelmethod.com/documents/Apame%20solver%20v3.0%20Tutorial.pdf (see basic example) may be you get some idea what kind of edge sorting I need to create input file from MMA.